# How do I turn a query string into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, query-string, urldecode

I’m using Ruby on Rails 4.2.7.  How do I take an encoded query string, like

```
submitbutton=View&a=b&d=%26%26
```

and turn it into a hash of name value pairs in which the values are url-unencoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CGI.parse`

```
CGI.parse('submitbutton=View&a=b&d=%26%26')
#=> {"submitbutton"=>["View"], "a"=>["b"], "d"=>["&&"]}
```